# How to change AHCI to RAID again after booting previous RAID drive in AHCI mode

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, bios, raid

I recently cleared CMOS because of a motherboard problem, but I forgot to change the SATA setting to RAID 1 again prior to restarting the computer. I noticed this when I saw the Intel RST service not working. I tried to change it back to RAID 1 on BIOS, but when I do that, Windows won't boot and says that I have hard disk error and failed RAID.

How can I fix this without reinstalling Windows or losing all my data?

System specs:

- 64-bit Windows 10
- Asus motherboard Gryphon Z87
- RAID 1